# System.NotSupportedException when trying to get an element from list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

The error also shows this:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] GetRoleById(Int32)'
> method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I only want to list the elements where the `Role` of a `User` equals `Bereichsleitung`.

`GetRoleByID` returns a `List` of `string`

```
 var model =
                db.Urlaubantrag.OrderByDescending(x => x.Jahr)
                    .Where(a => userdao.GetRoleById(a.Urlauber_ID).Contains("Bereichsleitung"))
                    .ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
            return View(model);
```

Anybody got an idea where the exact problem might be?

Comment: I think the problem might be that `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method GetRoleById`. Aka you are trying to use a C# function inside a SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, It's not `LINQ to Entities`, it's `LINQ to SQL`. And problem - `LINQ to SQL` can not translate method `GetRoleById` into sql code.

You can load **all** data from table and filter in code like this:

```
 var model =
             db.Urlaubantrag.OrderByDescending(x => x.Jahr)
                 .ToArray()
                 .Where(a => userdao.GetRoleById(a.Urlauber_ID).Contains("Bereichsleitung"))
                 .ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
```

This way is very unoptimal, because it load many rows that can be filtered.

So, you need to analize your `GetRoleById` and replace it with methods, that can be translated to sql.

Comment: And as the object is called user*DAO* and it is in fact a "real" DAO object it should be translatable to a sql query.
BTW: GetRole(...).Contains(<string>) would never pass our code review.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call methods inside the expression. You need to first materialize the queries you are referring first and then use the materialized lists in the queries.